# Diophantine equations

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Can I rigorously generate all possible solutions to the following system of Diophantine equations:

$x^2+y^2+z^2= a^2 +b^2+c^2+d^2=t^2$

Comment: The formula is long, but not a problem.

Comment: There are infinite solutions to your problem; the smallest solution demonstrates the process:
$$5^2+12^2+84^2=3^2+4^2+12^2+84^2=85^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the system of equations.

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&X^2+Y^2+Z^2=T^2\\&A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2=T^2\end{aligned}\right.$$

If we do the replacement.

$$p=r^2+n^2+q^2+j^2-i^2-v^2$$

$$k=r^2+n^2+q^2+j^2+i^2-v^2-2(r+n+q-v)i$$

$$s=r^2+n^2+q^2+j^2+v^2-i^2-2(r+n+q-i)v$$

$$b=2(i+v-r-n-q)j$$

$$t=r^2+i^2+v^2-n^2-q^2-j^2+2(n+q-i-v)r$$

$$c=q^2+i^2+v^2-r^2-n^2-j^2+2(n+r-i-v)q$$

$$a=n^2+i^2+v^2-r^2-q^2-j^2+2(q+r-i-v)n$$

Then the solution will have the form:

$$X=2ps$$

$$Y=2ks$$

$$Z=p^2+k^2-s^2$$

$$T=p^2+k^2+s^2=t^2+c^2+a^2+b^2$$

$$A=2at$$

$$B=2bt$$

$$C=2ct$$

$$D=a^2+b^2+c^2-t^2$$

Comment: Could you please provide some motivation for your solution.

Comment: @Supermario I don't understand Your question. It is necessary to solve the equation and write the answer.  $T=p^2+k^2+s^2=t^2+c^2+a^2+b^2$ Instead of solving the system of equations to solve this equation.

Comment: How did you come up with the replacement?

Comment: @Supermario the standard formula for any sum of squares.

Comment: I am new to Diophantine Equations. Could you please give a source from where I could read more about this problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Supermario no. Equations decide. Can in my Blog to see if any interesting.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What do you mean by equations decide?

Comment: @Supermario as these equations must be solved.

Comment: @individ your answer may be correct but your explanation is sub par.  Not only does it not exist, your responses to comments are short, kurt, and assuming.  Undoubtedly you're an accomplished mathematician, yet if you're so great, you should be able to write down an explanation any novice with an interest can follow.

Comment: @individ your blog is not enlightening

Answer (score 0):

## Answer in progress

---

Let's first consider solving the equation $$x^2+y^2+z^2=t^2.$$ Let $0\le x \le y \le z \le t$. Let us introduce dummy variables $p$ and $q$ and substitute them as follows: $$(x-p)^2+(y+p)^2+(z+q)^2=(t+q)^2.$$ Substituting two dummy variables allows us to express one of the variables in terms of the other, when expanding and simplifying with the condition that $x^2+y^2+z^2=t^2$. Given the inequalities, this particular substitution will guarantee small sizes of $p$ and $q$ terms since a lot will cancel out. Expand this and we find that it is true if: $p^2-p(x-y)\pm q(z\mp t)=0$ Now let us make this simpler by substituting $q=p^2+p$. This allows us to cancel out a $p$ factor and reduce to a first-degree polynomial. This also allows to connect a coefficient to a $p$ value so if we want to set the left hand side to $0$, it is sufficient that the *coefficient* is $0$ where the coefficient is not in terms of $p$. It is also sufficient to consider just one case of $(\pm, \mp)$, so let's pick the $(+,-)$. We now have: $$-x+y+z-t + p(1+z-t)=0$$ where $1+z-t$ is the coefficient. Let $t=1$ and $z=0$. So $-x+y=1$. Now let $y=1$ and $x=0$ to achieve this condition. Substitute it all back into the original equation, rewrite $(-p)^2=p^2$ and voila: $$p^2+(p+1)^2+(p^2+p)^2=(p^2+p+1)^2$$ Now substitute $p$ with $p/q$ and multiply through by $q^4$, so we have: $$(pq)^2+(pq+q^2)^2+(p^2+pq)^2=(p^2+pq+q^2)^2$$

---

Fun curio, this identity can be further generalised as follows:

If $ac-bd=1$ then for all $p$ and $q$, $$\big(p^2(a^2+ab+b^2)+pq+q^2(c^2+cd+d^2)\big)^2=$$ $$\big(ap^2(a+b)+pq+dq(c+d)\big)^2+$$ $$\big(bp^2(a+b)+pq+cp^2(c+d)\big)^2+$$ $$(abp^2-pq+cdq^2)^2$$

If you want, see if you can find this generalisation from the one above, which is just the special case $(a,b,c,d)=(1,0,1,0)$. Anyways, back to topic.

---

Let us now use the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity to finish this off. We can use the famous Pythagorean identity: $$(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2=(x^2+y^2)^2$$ and BF: $$(m a^2+ n b^2)(m c^2 + n d^2) = (m a c\pm n b d)^2 + m n (a d\mp bc)^2$$ Let $m=1$ and $n=1$. Then substitute $a\mapsto a^2-b^2$, $b\mapsto 2ab$, $c\mapsto c^2-d^2$ and $d\mapsto 2cd$. By Pythagoras's identity, this will transform the BF equality to expressing $(a^2+b^2)^2(c^2+d^2)^2$ as the sum of two squares. Finally, substitute $p=a^2+b^2$ and $q=c^2+d^2$ to effectively write $(pq)^2$ as the sum of two squares. The next part we require is then writing $$(p^2+pq)^2+(q^2+pq)^2=(p+q)^2(p^2+q^2)$$ as a sum of two different non-trivial squares, but I'll work on this part when I have more time.